# Why does an alert in onPress of a Button crash the expo app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

This code works.

```
<Button
  onPress = {() => testfn(this.state.text)}
  title = 'Send'
  color = '#1DA237'
/>

function testfn(theString) {
  alert(theString);
}
```

But this code crashes the expo app on build.

> ```
> <Button
>   onPress = {() => alert(this.state.text)}
>   title = 'Send'
>   color = '#1DA237'
> />
> ```

Can anybody clarify for me why that is?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I am running Android 6.0 on an LG G3 with Expo client version 1.18.4

Comment: BTW what is 'alert' here ? are u using functional or class component. Some more code could help

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: @RaviRaj https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Comment: @AlexanderIgnácz There was no error message, it literally crashed after it was done loading up to 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import alert from `react-native`

```
import {
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
```

Then call it like below:

```
function testfn(theString){
   Alert.alert(theString);
}
```

or

```
<Button
  onPress = {() => Alert.alert(this.state.text)}
  title = 'Send'
  color = '#1DA237'
/>
```

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I still don't know why it didn't give me an error though and instead just crashed. Usually it would give me something like `Can't find variable: Alert`.

Comment: `alert` is Javascript function, hence it will be available to you while development, but upon bundling, it will not be accessible.